# Тело запроса CURL POST

Tags: php

Добрый день, подскажите как отправить в теле запроса свой JSON, есть стандартный скрипт

```html
<?php
/**
* http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php
*/
/**
* Send a POST request using cURL
* @param string $url to request
* @param array|string $post values to send
* @param array $options for cURL
* @internal param array $get
* @return string
*/
function curl_post($url, $post = null, array $options = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST =>0,//unsafe, but the fastest solution for the error " SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK"
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>0, //unsafe, but the fastest solution for the error " SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK"
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));

    if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)){
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

и мне нужно на этот адрес

```
curl_post("https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0/orders/add?access_token=$access_token&requestTimeout=10000");
```

Добавить ещё свой JSON, как это сделать?) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо добавить корректный  `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.  Можете так:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0/orders/add?access_token=$access_token&requestTimeout=10000';  
$ch = curl_init($url);
$jsonDatas = array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key2' => 'value2'
);

$jsonDatasEncoded = json_encode($jsonDatas);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!)